# Non-typographical evidence of V being pronounced as [w]

Tags: classical-latin, phonetics, alphabet

According to a consensus of Latin scholars, the letter V in ancient Latin was pronounced as [w]. This seems to make sense, because there was no distinguishing between V and U, so the letter V could mark either the vowel [u] or its semivocalic counterpart [w] (much like with the letter I).

Is there any other evidence for this pronunciation? I saw some people challenging this view, so I would like to hear about some more evidence.

Comment: I seem to recall a story involving "figs" (cauneas) being confused for "beware of leaving" (cave ne eas).

Comment: @brianpck You recall your Cicero well.

Comment: "I saw some people challenging this view" - whom did you have in mind? imho most Latinists agree on this.

Comment: Actually the letter V stands for three phonemes: /w/, /u/. and /u:/.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The best way we know that consonantal V was pronounced as /w/ is from transcriptions of Latin words in other languages. For example, the Roman name Valerius is transcribed as Ουαλεριος (Oualerios) in Greek inscriptions. Greeks did not have a /w/ sound, but if you pronounce ου (ou) plus a vowel quickly enough, you get an approximate to it. You do not, though, get close to /v/.

Incidentally, we also know when the sound shifted, as later transcriptions have Βαλεριος, where the Greek beta had turned into a /v/ (as it is in Modern Greek).

The standard reference for pronunciation of Latin and Greek is W. Sydney Allen's two volumes, *Vox Latina* and *Vox Graeca*, and they're both worth checking out as a starting point if you're interested in the topic.

Answer (score 11):

W. Sydney Allen, in *Vox Latina*, page 41, gives several examples that support the [w] pronunciation of the consonantal *u* in Classical Latin.

The first example appears in the writings of [Nigidius Figulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigidius_Figulus) (Gellius, x, 4, 4), in which he apparently equates the lip position of the consonant and vowel sounds:

> in a discussion of the origins of language, he points out that in the words *tu* and *uos* the lips are protruded in the direction of the person addressed, whereas this is not the case in *ego* and *nos*

A second example comes from Cicero (*Div*, ii, 84), where he equates the sounds of *Cauneas* and *Caue ne eas*, which would only make sense if the *u* of *caue* was similar to that of *Cauneas*.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best evidence is outlined by cmw's answer about transcriptions into Greek.

However, even just looking at Latin itself, the distribution of Latin consonantal V makes it fairly obvious that it was "originally" [w]. It's harder to find out from the language-internal evidence ***when the sound passed from [w] to [v]***: much of the evidence I discuss below is consistent with this happening either late or early, since patterns in the distribution of sounds may lag sound changes (for comparison, present-day Russian [v], which is likewise from [w], still shows some [behavior that is made easier to explain by the earlier value](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38569); likewise, Sanskrit *va* continues to pattern as a semivowel corresponding to *u* even though it had developed a labiodental pronunciation already in [Panini's time](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6039/how-is-sanskrit-va-supposed-to-be-pronounced)).

The use of [w] in distantly etymologically related English words supports the reconstruction of [w] in the common ancestor that English and Latin share, Proto-Indo-European.

#### Evidence in Latin etymology that V derives from original [w]

Aside from V and U sharing the same spelling, there are a number of fairly regular alternations involving these two sounds in etymologically related words inside Latin. For example:

- "av" before vowels vs. "au" before consonants, as in *avis* vs. *auspex* (noted in a comment below by Draconis)
- "u" before a single vowel vs. "uv" before i + another vowel, as in  *fluo* vs. *fluvius*
- "av" in a word-initial syllable vs "u" in a word-internal syllable, as in *lavo* vs. *abluo*
- "[-uus" and "-vus" are variant forms of the same suffix](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/3054)

The V sound found in the above words was likely originally [w], because [w] and [u] are more similar and more likely to change into one another than [v] and [u].

The sound [u] is phonetically categorized as a "close back rounded vowel": "rounded" refers to the shape of the lips, which are brought together (there is a bit of variation between languages in the exact position of the lips). The sound [w] is pronounced mostly the same as [u], differing mainly in being non-syllabic. The sound [v] is further distinguished from [u] in several respects: 1) it is "labiodental", being pronounced with the lower lip against the upper teeth; 2) it has greater constriction than both [u] and [w], being categorized as a "fricative" consonant; 3) it lacks a "back" component.

Of course, once these patterns of alternation had been established, they could be maintained or extended to new pairs of words even after the sound change of [w] to [v].

For information on dating the change of [w] to [v], see the following question: [When did the consonant U (i.e., V) begin to be pronounced as the fricative [v] instead of [w]?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/325/when-did-the-consonant-u-i-e-v-begin-to-be-pronounced-as-the-fricative-v-i?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph -- what "alternation between [v] and [u] in Latin" do you mean?

Comment: @TKR: there are various examples of v-u alternation from Latin verb conjugation, as in solvo, solūtum, or with the compound naufragium from navis

Comment: I don't think etymology is a good proof. English also has *dissolve, dissolution* where /v/ alternates with /u/. It could equally likely be the case that Latin *v derives from /w/ but was pronounced as /v/ at any given point in time (as is indeed the case in later Latin and its descendants)

Comment: @ba: English "dissolve, dissolution" are loans. It's true that this argument doesn't provide any dates, which I had considered saying explicitly but ended up leaving out. When I wrote this answer, I was mainly thinking about what to say to somebody who wasn't convinced that Latin [v] had ever been pronounced as [w]--whether during the time period when we call the language "Latin" or in some earlier ancestor.

Comment: My favorite example for this alternation is av- "bird" + spic- "observe" = au-spic- "augur". There's ample evidence that the v is a consonant in _avis_ and a vowel in _auspex_, as both are well-attested words.

Comment: @Draconis. This is a bad example. <V> is a consonant/semivowel both is AVIS and in AVSPEX.