# When did consonantal "v" start being transcribed as "β"?

Tags: greek, alphabet, phonetics

Since I learned Latin using ecclesiastical pronunciation, I have a general interest in the shift from the classical pronunciation of "v" as /w/ to /v/.

This question is more focused though: I am interested in finding out **at what point Greek transcriptions of Latin names began using "β" instead of "ου" to transcribe Latin's consonantal "v".**

Cursory research reveals two close examples which use a different approach:

- Josephus (AD 37-100), in [*Jewish Antiquities* 15](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0145%3Abook%3D15%3Asection%3D345), transcribes "Varro" as "Οὐάρρωνος."
- Plutarch (AD 45-120), in his [*Life of Caesar* 5](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0130%3Achapter%3D5), transcribes "Vetus/eri" as "Βέτερι."

Something tells me, though, that Plutarch usually transcribes in the other way. I also recall that later works from Constantinople almost always use "β."

I am aware that there will not be a sharp dividing line, but I am interested in knowing if there are **any guidelines about time and place that will help me to predict which way a Greek text will transcribe this sound.**

Comment: Marcus Aurelius still uses *ou* for Latin v. I think I've seen it later.

Comment: Also related: http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/28/non-typographical-evidence-of-v-being-pronounced-as-w/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sturtevant, *The Pronunciation of Greek and Latin*, p. 88, has a relevant passage, though he doesn't go into details:

> Since Attic and Hellenistic Greek had no such sound as Classical Lat. *v*, namely [w], a substitution was necessary and the choice lay between ου and β. For a long time the former was preferred; but as [β] became a more and more frequent pronunciation of *v*, the digraph ου became less and less appropriate to represent it. This may be the whole explanation of the increasing preference for β which, **by the second or third century A.D.**, led to its regular use as the substitute for Lat. *v*.

Comment: This is great, but I was hoping for a little more detail, if this has ever been studied!

Comment: @brianpck, Sturtevant cites an article which he implies does go into more detail, but I haven't tried to dig it up: "G. B. Grundy, JPhS 1907.1-56".

Answer (score 5):

#### β is found as early as 2nd century BC per Grundy

Grundy<sup>1</sup>, who I've just started reading, says that the use of β to transcribe Latin V is attested in inscriptions as early as the 2nd century BC. Furthermore, Grundy says β is found 14% of the time as the transcription of Latin V in manuscripts of Polybius, who wrote in the second century BC.

Grundy gives the following percentages for β as a transcription of V in Greek inscriptions in first two centuries BC and second two centuries AD:

- 2nd Century BC Inscriptions: 27% (only a small sample: 4 with β, 11 with ου)
- 1st Century BC Inscriptions: 34%
- 1st Century AD Inscriptions: 29%
- 2nd Century AD Inscriptions: 33%

He also gives percentages for its occurrence in manuscripts of specific authors, such as Josephus (31%) Plutarch (49%), Dionysus of Halicarnassus (30%) and Diodorus (36%).

There is more data in the paper, which you can read at the link.

I found the data that Grundy reports surprising and I'm not sure why their implications for the timeline of the [w] > [v] change are not discussed more in more recent literature.

I did find the following article that, citing Grundy among others, argues that the change of Latin [w] to [β] had begun by the year 200BC: "The Greek Transliteration and Pronunciation of the Latin Consonant U", by Bradley Buszard, *Glotta,* Bd. 94 (2018), pp. 109-126.

#### Kantor (2017 dissertation) shows different frequencies looking at a different corpus

"The Second Column (Secunda) of Origen’s Hexapa in Light of Greek Pronunciation", a dissertation by Benjamin Paul Kantor (2017), contains a section on Latin transcribed into Greek papyri, most of which are "bilingual Greco-Latin
glossaries" (page 134).

The corpora Kantor considers show a much higher percentage of transcription as ου in the first and second centuries AD; in fact, β for V is only found before the 4th century AD in one text (containing three examples) (SB III.I. 6304, page 140).

Kantor says that the low frequency of β is probably related to the genre of the texts in the corpus:

> Even though Latin v was pronounced as [β] already from the first or second century CE in Egypt, glossarial and grammatical texts used for language instruction maintained the old pronunciation [w] up until the fourth century CE. During this period, language-learning texts represented Latin v with ου, reflecting an archaic or standard pronunciation, and non-didactic texts represented Latin v with β (e.g., SB III.I. 6304), reflecting everyday colloquial pronunciation. After the fourth century CE, it seems that the pronunciation of Latin v as [β] had become so universal that even in grammatical texts Latin v was represented with β.

(page 141).

I find this explanation quite plausible, since it's not too hard to come up with examples of similar archaisms in transcription or pronunciation of modern languages (such as the fact that ["sch" (or French "chtch") is still commonly seen as a transcription of the Russian letter Щ](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14220/why-is-%D1%89-transliterated-as-shch), which was previously pronounced [ɕtɕ] but is now pronounced [ɕː]).

Similarly, Grundy argues that the transcription ου was favored in the spelling of official names due to conservatism well after the appearance of the first transcriptions in β (pages 15-17).

---

1. "[The transliteration and pronunciation of the Latin letter V](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc2.ark:/13960/t6833pj7x&view=1up&seq=3&skin=2021)", by G.B.
   Grundy, 1907, mentioned in a comment by TKR