# Why does uacuus have three syllables?

Tags: etymology

I stumbled across [this question on the pronunciation of 'vacuum'](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/21560/why-does-vacuum-have-two-us-and-how-is-it-pronounced) in the “linguistics” forum.

My question is: If uacuus is *wak+wo- why does uacuus have three syllables, but uiuus, paruus, caluus etc. have only two? Is there a rule that says that *wu remains after sonants (including l, r) but becomes *uu otherwise?

Comment: "Equus" might be an interesting one to compare against.

Answer (score 11):

The adjective *uacuus* is formed from the verb *uacō* (“I am empty, void”) with the help of the ‎adjective-forming suffix *-uus*. This suffix has 2 variants, the 1-syllable one and the 2-syllable one.

The 1-syllable form *-vus* is used after vowels (*flā-vus, vī-vus*), after L (*cal-vus*), and R (*par-vus, cor-vus*), and the 2-syllable form of that suffix, *-uus* is used after all other other consonants, like in your word *vac-uus*, with the exception of QU. In this last case, the form -us is used (*multiloqu-us, obliqu-us*).

Comment: Some more examples (from Weiss 297-8) supporting this pattern: *salvus, clīvus, rāvus, rīvus, fulvus, furvus, helvus, arvus* vs. *caeduus, continuus, dīviduus, exiguus, irriguus, pāscuus, praecipuus*.

Comment: @AlexB. I think Yellow Sky is using the "v" and "u" to differentiate between the one syllable and two syllable forms. The Romans would not have differentiated the symbols, but we, in the modern day, do so that is what he is getting at (1 syllable following vowels and liquids, 2 syllables after consonants).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a well-known rule (see Leumann 1977: 132-133, Tronskii 1960: 101, Weiss 2009/2011: 124 and many others).

Weiss puts it this way,

> **“An unstressed short vowel between a liquid and u̯ is syncopated”** (p. 124):

*b<sup>h</sup>olh<sub>1</sub>i-u̯os > *foliu̯os > fulvus

*sl̩h₂u̯os (or *sl̩h₂euos) > *salau̯os > salvus

*arau̯om > arvum

cf. Leumann "Postkons. lat. u̯ (v) vor Vokal aus vokal. u: vorhistorisch hinter *r l*; hinter anderen Konsonanten aus Versnot bei Daktylikern, spaeter allgemein im Vulgaerlatein" (p. 132).

It occurred in the pre-literary period.

**Exception:**

> “If the vowel in the preceding syllable was long, the syncope did not occur until the post-Plautine period:

mīluus > mīlvus

lārua > lārva

*pēleu̯is > pēluis > pēlvis

Comment: I don’t see any evidence for *sala-wus, with or without syncopation. The cognates (e.g. Skt sarva-, Gk. *holwos > holos) point to *salw-us.

Comment: @fdb in Latin *-lu̯- develops to -ll- (hence, sollus). But salvus is usually explained with syncope (thus,*-lu̯- remains). See Leumann para 60 or Weiss (p. 162, point 9). NB: Unable to fix formatting/italics/reconstructed forms.

Comment: @fdb I assume you've looked it up in Beekes or de Vaan? Because they do address the point you raised. (Beekes: *slh2-eu-)

Comment: de Vaan actually writes *slH-u- with unidentified laryngeal. The laryngeal is posited to explain the /a/ in the first syllable.

Comment: And you've read Nussbaum 1997? It's on academia.edu

Comment: Yes, but you need to read de Vaan with caution. Incidentally, he did mention two hypotheses on p. 572.

Comment: Link to the [Nussbaum paper](https://www.academia.edu/1209517/The_Saussure_Effect_in_Latin_and_Italic). The laryngeal in the root is apparently posited on the basis of evidence from Irish and Luvian. The Greek and Sanskrit forms by themselves would suggest *solwo-*, which wouldn't account for the Latin *a*. I'm not sure where *salau̯os* is supposed to come from -- shouldn't *sl̩h₂u̯os* give *slāvus*?

Comment: PIE *CRHC has been argued to give Latin CaRaC instead of the usual CRāC, but only when the R was accented; some recent proposed examples [here](http://www.academia.edu/15713840/Observations_on_the_palma_rule_handout_). But I don't see why it would be accented in *sl̩h₂u̯os, an adjective, which unlike those examples -- all nouns -- could not show nominal accent retraction.

Comment: @TKR Weiss puts it very nicely, "There is only one sound change that **may** require the conditioning factor of the PIE accent" (p. 110), "**It is thought by some** that this is the treatment when the resonant was accented" and "This conditioning factor ... **could well have been true** for Latin also, although the evidence is difficult to deal with and far from conclusive."

Comment: But if the *palma* rule is wrong, then *sl̩h₂u̯os* should definitely give *slāvus* rather than *salau̯os* > *salvus*, no? I don't think it's debated that the usual reflex of *CRHC* is *CRāC*.

Comment: @TKR I did *not* say it was wrong (what you call the palma rule - one specific application, in Latin, of what is usually known as the Saussure effect). As for salvus and its IE comparanda: there have been lots of proposals, for example, Lucien van Beek https://www.academia.edu/5945722/The_Saussure_effect_in_Greek_a_reinterpretation_of_the_evidence (esp. pp. 155-157) and Pronk 2011 https://www.academia.edu/1000907/The_Saussure_effect_in_Indo-European_Languages_Other_Than_Greek (pp. 188-189 are very important!) Let me know what you think.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you, but the Saussure effect is not the same as the *palma* rule -- the former is loss of a laryngeal next to a resonant in an o-grade form, the latter is PIE *CRHC* > Lat. *CaRaC* when R is accented. Thanks for the links! I'm looking at Pronk's discussion of *salvus*, but I still don't understand his derivation. He derives it from *slh₂eu-m* > Italic *salavem* (which bypasses the *palma* question), but shouldn't that rather give *solau-*, with *ol* as the normal reflex of syllabic *l*?

Comment: @TKR, no, because **PIE *CR̥HV > Italic *CaRV** (Weiss, p. 104, VII.A)

Comment: @TKR Beekes 2011 also reminds that in such cases (CR̥HV), the vowel was colored by h2, so PIE *h2e > Latin *a (p. 152) - that's how you get the second a. I think it's pretty neat and everything should be clear by now?

Comment: Ah, that's the sound change I was missing! That makes sense, thanks.