# Is U between NG and a vowel always a consonant?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

Is the letter U (whether spelled as U or V) between NG and a vowel always a consonant?
It is at the very least a useful rule of thumb, but I wonder if there are counterexamples to this rule (or tendency).
The main examples that come to mind are *lingua* and *sanguis* and *pinguis* and *unguis*, all bisyllabic, where U is a consonant.
Does it perhaps depend on which vowel follows or do the surroundings not help detect counterexamples?

Comment: You can add *stinguere* and its compounds, *pinguis*, and *unguis* to that list, and that's it for the 2000 most common Latin words. It feels significant that phonemically this isn't /ɡ/ + /w/ but /ɡʷ/. If you remove the <n> from consideration and just look for *guV*, there's only *exiguus* without the glide, which may be a late coining from *exigere* + *-uus*. There are also few words matching *kuV* where the <u> is vocalic, by the way: mainly *acuere*, *vacuus*, and *cuius* (special because it used to be *quoius*, which did have the glide but lost it to dissimilation when its o > u).

Comment: @Cairnarvon The observation that there are no counterexamples but just more examples within the most common words would make a nice answer. That any counterexample would have to be rare is a practical answer even if not definitive. Can you turn that comment into an answer?

Comment: I don't think it's a satisfactory answer, I don't think my frequency list is sufficiently exhaustive (2000 words is less than 10% of an average person's vocabulary, and it doesn't include inflected forms), and I'm particularly bothered by *acuere*, which feels hard to explain if there *is* a real phenomenon here. I hope my comment can spur someone more knowledgeable/with better access to resources in a useful direction, though. (Also I just realised *cuius* doesn't match *kuV* because the <i> is consonantal.)

Comment: Cser 2020 mentions eleven words (and their derivatives) where ngv is found: anguis, inguen, languor, lingua, ninguit, pinguis, sanguis, stinguere, tinguere, unguis, unguere (p. 21).

Comment: He also writes that in poetry [w] **never** scans as [u] (when following a consonant) cf. "a word like *aqua* or *inguen* is **always two syllables**" (p. 31; emphasis mine - Alex B.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Practically always, but not in *relangŭit* in the poetry of Ovid

The sequence "NGV" + vowel letter is only found in a small number of words plus their derivatives. The pronunciation is nearly always non-syllabic, analyzed either as /ngw/ or /ngʷ/ depending on your theoretical preferences. I prefer /ngw/. (Technically, there are other possible analyses like treating V+the following vowel as a rising diphthong, or treating V as a non-syllabic vowel [u̯] instead of a consonant phoneme /w/, but I haven't seen recent treatments that advance either of those analyses for Classical Latin.)

Syllabic *u* occurs in the perfect (but not the present) stem of the verb *languēscō* and its derivatives such as *[relanguēscō](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=relanguesco)* according to [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlanguesco). Using PHI Latin word seach, I found these two examples of forms ending in *langŭit* in Ovid:

- "inposito fratri moribunda relanguit ore" (*Metamorphoses* 6.290-291)

  i͞npŏsĭ|tō frā|trī morĭ|bu͞ndă rĕ|**la͞ngŭĭ**|t‿ōre;
- "cum bene pertaesum est, animoque relanguit ardor" (*Amores* 2.9b.27)

  cu͞m bĕnĕ |pe͞rta͞e|su͞m‿est,‿ănĭ|mōquĕ rĕ|**la͞ngŭĭ**|t‿a͞rdor

  (Macrons used here to mark heavy syllables, not long vowels; feet separated with |)

In constrast, the *langues-* of the present stem scans as two heavy syllables in the four places where it occurs in Ovid (*Amores* 2.10.35, *Metamorphoses* 8.523, *Fasti* 2.775, *Tristia* 3.3.39).

#### Explanation of the syllabic U in *relanguit*

I think there might be an etymological or morphological explanation for the syllabic -u- in this context. I have a vague memory of Manu Leumann saying in *Lateinische Laut- und Formenlehre* that the perfect ending -uī in Latin verbs of the second conjugation developed from an earlier sequence containing the vowel e, like *-eui/evi; unfortunately, I don't have access to this work right now, so I can't check for the citation or the details of the derivation (for example, I don't know how the e here would get to be short instead of long). Anyway, if this is correct, it might be that *langŭ-* in *langŭit* is a simplification of some earlier sequence like langʷeu- where some form of *-e- originally intervened between the labial(ized) consonant at the end of the root and the labial perfect suffix -u-/-v-.

Similarly, Lewis and Short shows alternation between -qu- in the present stem and -cu- in the perfect stem for *[liquēscō](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dliquesco), licŭī* and its prefixed forms. For example, Ovid uses the form "dēlĭcŭit" (*Metamorphoses* 4.253, 7.381, *Tristia* 3.10.15).

Given the rarity of /ngu/ before a vowel and the apparent lack of minimal pairs between /ngw/ and /ngu/, the scansion of *-ngui-* as *-ngŭi-* in the two lines above could perhaps be interpreted as a case of poetic diaeresis where /u/ stands for /w/, an explanation found in *The Principles of Latin Grammar,* by Peter Bullions (1851) ([page 300](https://archive.org/details/principleslatin01bullgoog/page/n320/mode/2up?q=relanguit)) and *Adam's Latin Grammar* by Allen Fisk (1833) ([page 186](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Adam_s_Latin_Grammar/H6IAAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=relanguit)). However, *An elementary manual of Latin prosody* by William Ramsay (1859), specifically says that *relangŭit* is always four syllables ([page 69](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_elementary_manual_of_Latin_prosody/e5ACAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22relanguit%22+syllable&pg=PA69&printsec=frontcover)), and so is not analogous to poetic pronunciations like *silŭa* where the word had a Classical Latin pronunciation with non-syllabic -v-.

I'm inclined to agree with Ramsay. Non-syllabic *-qu-* and *-gu-* have often been analyzed as unitary phonemes /kʷ/ and /gʷ/ (although that phonemic analysis is arguable for Classical Latin). I feel like they would not alternate with a consonant-vowel sequence as easily as the sequence /lw/ (which I believe often derived in Latin from an earlier /lu/ or /l/ + vowel + /w/ sequence—a [comment by Alex B.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/3054/why-does-uacuus-have-three-syllables/3055#comment7933_4063) says that original /lw/ is supposed to have changed in Latin to /ll/). And I am not aware of any word that displays variable scansion between /ngw/ and /ngu/: as far as I know, all other words spelled with "NGV" + vowel letter always scan with /ngw/. Surprisingly, however, there are some alleged cases of [diaeresis of *-qu-* to *-cu-* [ku] in poetry](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14762/variation-between-syllabic-and-non-syllabic-v-in-what-contexts-is-it-possible)—I've asked a separate question to try to study these in more depth.

#### No other examples that I know of

I'm not sure if there are any other verbs that can have a perfect stem ending in /ngu/ with syllabic /u/, but it seems not. Here are possible candidates and my research so far:

- *Langueo* is the only second-conjugation verb ending in *-ngueo.* Aside from *languēscō* and its derivatives, there seems to be one other inchoative third-conjugation verb ending in *-nguēscō:* *[pinguēscō](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpinguesco)* (along with prefixed *[compinguēscō](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcompinguesco))*. However, there seem to be no attested perfect forms for *(-)pinguēscō.*
- *Ung(u)o*: Dictionaries treat it as a variant of *ungo* with the same perfect stem, *unx-.* There are hits in PHI for *ungui* but I can't tell whether any are a perfect form; it exists separately as the present passive infinitive form of *unguo* and as a form of *unguis,* both of which would be pronounced with /ngw/.
- *[Stinguo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=stinguo)* is rarely used unprefixed. The prefixed forms *distinguo, ex(s)tinguo* have perfect stems ending in *-tinx-* according to Lewis and Short. These verbs have passive infinitives in *-nguī* and present third-person singular forms in *-nguit*, which makes it difficult to search for any possible alternative perfect forms in -u-.