# Can a same poet use both U/V (vowel/consonant) variants of the same stem?

Tags: pronunciation, poetry, scansion

There are some words that poets use in more than one way. For example the word *deorsum*, usually 3 syllables (dĕ-or-sum), but sometimes the poets allowed themselves some freedom, and had it as 2 syllables word (deor-sum?). The same poet might use both forms, here are examples noted in [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=deorsum) from *De Rerum natura*:

> quin vacu/um per i/nane de/orsum /cuncta fe/rantur. (2.202); 3 syllables

> pondera/, quant(um) in/ s(e) est, deor/sum de/ducere/ pugnent. (2.205); 2 syllables

But what about another possible variation, such as in the stem (maybe just in the perfect stem) of the verb *solvo*. *soluit* is usually of 2 syllables (sol-vit), *u* being consonant. But there are instance where *u* is treated as vowel, so we end up with 3 syllables (so-lu-it).Like in Catullus:

> quod zonam soluit diu ligatam.  (Catul.Carm.2b.13) [not sure how to scan this, but L&S has *soluit* here as 3 syl.]

Can we expect, like *deorsum*, that the same poet will use at one time *sol-vit* and at another time *so-lu-it*? (Of course this question is not restricted to *solvo* (I'm simply short of examples), it is rather about those cases of *u* being handled as consonant or vowel.). Or rather this kind of variation is more time-based, and hence it could not be used in both forms by a given author?

In other words, in *De Rerum Nataura* we find apparently ambiguous first foot:

> dissoluat natura neque ad nihilum interemat res (1.216) [dis-sol/vat or dis-so-lu/at].

Do we know in that verse whether the first foot is dactyl or spondee?

Comment: related https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/14762/39